2020 Moderator Election
As a result of the feedback we received for the 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check, we are confident that we can run our first full election without fear of it failing due to low candidate numbers.

First, we would like to thank everybody for their support. Second, we would like to thank everyone for their willingness to step up and help out in fulfilling the roles that we are soon to have open here.

Our 2020 Moderator Election page is live here: 2020 Moderator Election.
There are some dates that we would like to point out:

nomination period begins
on Jun 29 at 20:00
election begins
on Jul 6 at 20:00
election ends
on Jul 14 at 20:00

This means that:

question collection begins

on Jun 22



If anyone is curious as to what question collection is and/or entails, here are a couple of meta posts from other sites where they have already started the process this year:
ELL: 2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection
The Workplace: 2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection
Ask Ubuntu: 2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

The last thing we want to remind everyone is the number of:

moderator positions available
3

We will have a least four candidates running for three positions.

This is our first election and it seems like we are off to a good start. Let's keep the momentum going!

If anyone would like to calculate their own Candidate Score they can use this SEDE query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer.
One thing to keep in mind, though, is that:

this is based on data which is updated every Sunday, so it will be out of date to a certain degree. 

